# how to manipulate a Jquery.ajax datatype

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "website/Function",
    data: '&link=' + link,
    contentType: "application/text; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (data) {
        var Link = data.toString();
        $('link').val(Link);
    }
});
```

The value from link will be something like:

```
xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">blah /string
```

How can I manipulate this return value just to extract 'blah'?

'blah' can be dynamic

Thanks to anyone who helps.

Comment: `console.log` helps you find what's in returned data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build off of ulvund's answer: use jQuery.parseXML():

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EH2M9/4/)

```
var xmlData = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><string xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"> blah </string> ";

$("button").click(function() {
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xmlData);
    $xml = $(xmlDoc);
    $('#result').text($xml.find("string").text());
});
```

This is basically taken right off of jQuery's demo for [parseXML()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var result = $('link').find("string").text();
```

Comment: Hi Uvund, sorry i should of mentioned that the data i want to find is dynamic